# Domain nameservers change in godaddy

Tags: api, shared-hosting, nameservers

i am using GoDaddy API to change domain nameservers and sometimes i get an errors: 
`{"code":"FAILED_NAME_SERVER_VALIDATION","message":"Failed to update nameserversDuplicate IP address","name":"ApiError"}` or `{"code":"FAILED_NAME_SERVER_VALIDATION","message":"Failed to update nameserversDuplicate nameservers","name":"ApiError"}`
I tried to google it, but not found anything useful. What it means and how to fix this? Thank in advance.

Comment: Please post the string you are submitting

Answer (score 0):

I interpret that as the validation on the string is failing, are you sure there are no new lines or invalid characters in the string you are submitting?

Comment: I'm sure all characters are valid

Comment: And query not require any ip address, what means "Duplicate IP address"?